# Matching huge tables data in Distributed Environment

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, nosql, hadoop2, in-memory-database

I have a shell script job which provides the input data that needs to be match and suppressed with n number of huge tables (Table size varies from 20 million to 150 million records). Multiple job may be submitted at the same time

Input data size varies from 500k to 3MM records.
No of tables varies from 5 to 40.
Huge tables data will be updated on real-time basis;
Matching Column will have index created.

Currently I am doing this task using Mysql on Linux Sever (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2637 v3 @ 3.50GHz and Ram 128Gb) which is taking long time. I have provided the shell script which accepts input data file as argument and hit the database to execute below queries and get the clean data back.I am looking for the better approach to this problem.

```sql
delete a from inputTableName a, table1 b where a.email=b.email;
delete a from inputTableName a, table2 b where a.email=b.email;
delete a from inputTableName a, table3 b where a.email=b.email;
delete a from inputTableName a, table4 b where a.email=b.email;
delete a from inputTableName a, table5 b where a.email=b.email;
delete a from inputTableName a, table6 b where a.email=b.email;
```

Need the result in 3 to 5 minutes per job. Wanted to know if this problem can be solved using distributed approach. I am open to use any language or technology.

Comment: Do you mean "distributed?" What, if any, programming languages can you use?  (php? C#? Java? Python?) And, please [edit] your question to describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I mean distributed and I am open to use any programming language or technology. I have edited my question, please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Are you running these queries concurrently or consecutively? Are a.email and b.email indexed?

Comment: my shell script does execute queries sequentially, but multiple persons can invoke this shell script at a time. a.email and b.email both are indexed.

Comment: Hi Dave and Jones, do you have any ideas to share to overcome this ...still stuck with same problem. Thanks in advance.